# How to generate ctags for system verilog?

Tags: system-verilog, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I want to generate `tags` file for system verilog.

I found this really helpful [link](https://coderwall.com/p/fy7stg/vim-and-systemverilog), and I was able to generate UVM tags file.

But my question is about SV. Since there is no separate sv files, the language is build into the compiler itself, how do i go about creating tags file for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe what i am looking for is not exactly tags, lets say i have a queue in my code, i want something that would identify this as a queue and provide me its access methods.

Answer (score 3):

What was wrong with the link you provided? here are some others

https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/ctags-systemverilog
http://hackdut.blogspot.com/2015/03/ctags-and-vim-to-work-with-systemverilog.html

Comment: It helps with generation of uvm tags, since uvm library is present in form of *.svh/*.sv file and ctags can parse it. I am asking how to create tags for native sv, since i dont have the *.sv/*.svh files for them, they are build into the compiler itself.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "build into the compiler itself"

Comment: Dave, what i meant is that the sv language is part of the compiler. there are no separate *.sv/*.svh for system verilog as we have for UVM. what i am looking is a way to generate tags for sv lrm itself.

Comment: I think they are looking for auto tips for language constructs, not just for symbols like registers and modules in the source code, which is what ctags provides. I think they actually want something like a SystemVerilog language server protocol?

Answer (score 2):

For improved support of SystemVerilog you can try [Universal Ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags), where the Verilog parser was improved to also support SystemVerilog.

I also suggest that you use this [Verilog/SystemVerilog Vim Plugin](https://github.com/vhda/verilog_systemverilog.vim) that also includes some basic omni-completion.

Disclaimer: most of this is my work. Your mileage may vary, but feel free to report issues and ask for improvements.